# Which one is correct? "On a TV show" or "In a TV show"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

[This site](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2015/10/13/why_are_you_on_a_tv_show_but_in_a_movie_several_hypotheses.html) says:

We can say "**On/in a TV show**".

A British English textbook says "**In the TV show**".

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20a%20TV%20show%2Cin%20a%20TV%20show&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20TV%20show%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20TV%20show%3B%2Cc0) says there are more "**On a TV show**" than "**In a TV show**".

Which one is correct? "**On a TV show**" or "**In a TV show**"?

So, American says "**On a TV show**"? & British says "**In a TV show**".

There are more Americans than British people & that is why "**On a TV show**" is more popular, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **on** a TV show
>   **in** a TV show

both are commonly used and practically interchangeable.  It may be due to people trying to figure out *where* the TV show was when TV first came out.

> I saw it **on** the TV show. - *(commonly used)*
>   I saw it **in** the TV show. - *(commonly used)*
>   She stars **in** the TV show. - *(commonly used)*
>   She stars **on** the TV show - *(commonly used)*

But

> The show is **on** TV. - *(commonly used)*
>   The show is **in** TV. - *(never used)*

Other examples

> **in** a Broadway show - *(commonly used)*
>   **in** an opera - *(commonly used)*
>   **on** a Broadway show - *(never used)*
>   **on** an opera - *(never used)*

But nowadays

> Netflix **on** my computer - *(used to refer to shows and the application)*
>   Netflix **in** my computer - *(used two refer to the application)*

Answer (score 0):

In briefly, you can always (except some places) use "On" before the word TV without any kind of hesitation.

Examples:

> I saw a piece of news on the TV.
> I watched the program on the TV.

Comment: You normally **watch the news** (on TV), you normally **read a piece of news**